# RPM-BUILD- Spec file Understanding

Tags: linux

I am new in Linux. I want to create a rpm from tar.gz by rpmbuilder. But I am little bit confused about

## make PREFIX=/usr/ DESTDIR=%{?buildroot} install

I want to know what is happening by this. If I don't give the PREFIX and DESTDIR what will be happened.

Comment: That's not really a RPM building question; that just basic `make` command line syntax.  Spend some time learning about `make`, either by reading [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/) or maybe the [O'Reilly Book](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/make3/book/index.csp).

Comment: I am getting is one on rpm spec file thats why I mention this on as rpm building.

Answer (score 0):

1. **DESTDIR=%{?buildroot}** is required for installing to BUILDROOT folder. BUILDROOT folder must contain the same hierarchy of files that should exist after installing of the package, that is why we should install to it.
2. **PREFIX=/usr/** is used for installing not to */usr/local/* but to */usr/*, so your binaries will appear in */usr/bin/* folder, not in */usr/local/bin/*. Note that this */usr/* folder will exist in BUILDROOT during the work of rpmbuild (because of point 1).